# Python tools to perform interpolation of values at mesh centroids to mesh vertices?

Tags: python, mesh

I have a (n, m) array that represents a mesh of a real world property (e.g. elevation) where each row and column represents an equally spaced distance between measurements that were taken. The values of n and m can be fairly large. A smaller 6x6 version would look like this, for example (where each cell may be 10 m across):

[image: small_array]

I'd like to use Python to interpolate all the values at the vertices of the grid (and extrapolate to the vertices on the edge of the grid. i.e. calculating the values on all the red dots:

[image]

I have the coordinates of the centroids of each cell, as well as the coordinates of all the vertices. Are there any packages or tools in Python that would make this a straightforward task?

Answer (score 0):

One possibility is to do this via [smoothfit](https://github.com/nschloe/smoothfit), a project of mine. You first create a quad mesh ([meshzoo](https://github.com/nschloe/meshzoo) might help), then define your target positions `x0` with values `y0`, then solve with smoothfit.

```py
import meshzoo
import smoothfit

points, cells = meshzoo.rectangle_quad((0.0, 0.0), (7.0, 7.0), n=7)


x0 = [
    [0.5, 0.5],
    [1.5, 0.5],
    [2.5, 0.5],
    [3.5, 0.5],
    [4.5, 0.5],
    [5.5, 0.5],
    # ...
    [0.5, 5.5],
    # ...
    [5.5, 5.5],
]
y0 = [8.0, 8.0, 9.0, 8.0, 7.0, 6.0, 10.0, 9.0]

basis, u = smoothfit.fit(x0, y0, points, cells, lmbda=1.0e-4, solver="dense-direct")

# Write the function to a file
basis.mesh.save("out.vtu", point_data={"u": u})
```

This then gives you a function over the entire domain that is smooth and approximately fulfills your target values.

[image]